# Any equivalent to CCleaner for Android?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-desire, internal-storage

I found a few questions about freeing internal memory, but they're mainly about deleting apps, moving them to the SD card, or deleting the data/cache. I do that on regular basis so I am looking for something else.

Is there any kind of equivalent of [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) for Android? That would help me to find and delete files I can delete?

- HTC Desire on CM 7.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  [SDMaid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en) does an excellent job of finding files abandoned by the system such as interrupted Play APK downloads (cutely called the "basement corpse finder"), shrinking databases and emptying your caches.  It also lists files by size so you can find space hogs, etc.

Comment: Hmm, it says that SDMaid is intended for rooted devices. Any suggestions for non-rooted phones?

Comment: @ihtkwot Just like how you need administrator privileges on your pc to run ccleaner you need it on Android too.